# data_edit from DataEditR is converting numerics to integers

Tags: r, integer, numeric

I've come across what seems like a pretty cool package for interactively manipulating dataframes in R, but I've run into a rather annoying quirk in the code.

My code supplies the first line, and users must then add additional lines and input values under `Concentration factor,` such that in the first iteration:

```
Name,"Concentration factor","Li","B","Rb","Sr","Ba"
5x,5,2,11,210,3,1
```

becomes something like:

```
Name,"Concentration factor","Na","K","Rb","Cs","Ba"
5x,5,2,11,210,3,1
100x,100,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
500x,500,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
```

And the code takes over to makes some calculations based on the input under `Concentration factor.`

The problem is that when I input values in new rows with data_edit, these values are forced into integer types. If I define this row as numeric before and then use data_edit, it keeps converting to integers, which means I can't input fractional numbers.

Perhaps there is a simple work-around (and I realize I'm not doing this in the most efficient way), but I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.